# How to get post url in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way to get the post url of a site in google analytics.
What mean to post url is the url that will only appear on the console network of the browser and NOT the url link which can be seen above of the browser. 
It can be seen in this part of the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdmcn.png)

In short i want to get the other url of the site that is not placed in the address bar. Is it possible?

Im still new to google analytics.

The only thing i can get in google analytics is the get method urls of the site. Thanks!

Example of what i want to get in google analytics is like: sample.com/action/add/friend?id=41231

Answer (score 0):

If you can get that desired URL from the page or from Google Tag Manager you can use it as the value of the **page** parameter and send it as pageview to Google Analytics, i.e.:

```
ga ('send', 'pageview', page);
```

Where *page* is your URL or other string.
In this way you can replace it with the default value (which is the URL in the address bar).